# Difference of OpenCV Mat types

Tags: opencv

What are the differences between OpenCV `cv::Mat` types?

To be more specific, what is the difference between `CV_64F` and `CV_64FC1` or `CV_64FC2`? Which one should I use when I'm creating a `cv::Mat` object which will have `double` values?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`Cx` part shows **number of channels** in an image. That is, image of type `CV_64FC1` is simple grayscale image and has only 1 channel:

```
image[i, j] = 0.5
```

while image of type `CV_64FC3` is colored image with 3 channels:

```
image[i, j] = (0.5, 0.3, 0.7)
```

(in C++ you can check individual pixels as `image.at<double>(i, j)`)

`CV_64F` is the same as `CV_64FC1`. So if you need just 2D matrix (i.e. single channeled) you can just use `CV_64F`

---

**EDIT**

More generally, type name of a `Mat` object consists of several parts. Here's example for `CV_64FC1`:

- `CV_` - this is just a prefix
- `64`  - number of bits per base matrix element (e.g. pixel value in grayscale image or single color element in BGR image)
- `F`  - type of the base element. In this case it's `F` for float, but can also be `S` (signed) or `U` (unsigned)
- `Cx` - number of channels in an image as I outlined earlier