# error : sizes of input arguments do not match. cvTriangulatePoints

Tags: c, visual-studio, opencv, triangulation

I used the function cvTriangulatePoints (see doc :http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html ) on visual studio.
When I have one corresponding point per images (N=1) the code works but if I add a second point (N=2) I got the following error :
"error : sizes of input arguments do not match < Number of points must be the same> in cvTriangulatePoints." 
It's the first time I use cvTriangulatePoints with more than 1 corresponding points. Is it possible to add more points or do I have another error ?

```
CvMat* projMatr1;
CvMat* projMatr2;
CvMat* projPoints1;
CvMat* projPoints2;
CvMat* points4D;
int N = 2;

projMatr1 = cvCreateMat(3, 4, CV_64FC1);
projMatr2 = cvCreateMat(3, 4, CV_64FC1);
projPoints1 = cvCreateMat(2, N, CV_64FC1);
projPoints2 = cvCreateMat(2, N, CV_64FC1);
points4D = cvCreateMat(4, N, CV_64FC1);
// I fill the matrices with the opencv function cvSet2D()
cvTriangulatePoints(projMatr1, projMatr2, projPoints1, projPoints2, points4D);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When value of N (number of channels) is raised from 1 to 2, the last argument in `cvCreateMat` should also be changed from

```
CV_64FC1 to CV_64FC2. 
       ^           ^

projPoints1 = cvCreateMat(2, N, CV_64FC2);
projPoints2 = cvCreateMat(2, N, CV_64FC2);
points4D = cvCreateMat(4, N, CV_64FC2);
```

The *Cx* portion of the arguement refers to the number of channels.

More generally, type name of a `Mat` object consists of several parts. Here's example for `CV_64FC1`:

- `CV_` - library prefix
- `64`  - number of bits per base matrix element (e.g. pixel value in grayscale image or single color element in BGR image)
- `F`  - type of the base element. In this case it's `F` for float, but can also be `S` (signed) or `U` (unsigned)
- `Cx` - number of channels included in image

`...Cx` for you should be `...C2`
...*[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248926/difference-of-opencv-mat-types)*

Here is more information on *[CvType](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/CvType.html)*.