# Error when creating a 4x4 mat matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, mat

I am trying to create a 4x4 matrix with `cv::Mat(4,4,CV_64F, data_m);`, 
where data_m is a float array

```
float data_m[] = {rmatrix.at<float>(0,0),rmatrix.at<float>(0,1), rmatrix.at<float>(0,2), tvec[0],rmatrix.at<float>(1,0), rmatrix.at<float>(1,1), rmatrix.at<float>(1,2), tvec[1], rmatrix.at<float>(2,0), rmatrix.at<float>(2,1), rmatrix.at<float>(2,2), tvec[2],0.f ,0.f ,0.f, 1.f};
```

and rmatrix is a 3x3 matrix, tvec is a 3x1 vector.

However, when initializing `translation_m`

```
cv::Mat translation_m = cv::Mat(4,4,CV_64F, data_m);
```

the last eight elements were not successfully initialized in `translation_m` matrix. It returns some weird alien number like `4.59121e-41`.

Does anyone have an insight on what is going on here?

Comment: `CV_64F` and `float` appears incompatible to me. Wouldn't be `double` more appropriate? (I must admit I haven't experience in OpenCV but `float` is the 32 bit floating point, `double` the 64 bit. I found [SO: Difference of OpenCV Mat types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19249237/7478597) which might be of help.)

Comment: If I understood the doc. right, `cv::Mat translation_m = cv::Mat(4,4,CV_64F, data_m);` calls [`cv::Mat::Mat(int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step = AUTO_STEP)`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a). Please, note the `void *data` argument (which cannot support any type check). It seems my above concerns might be justified.

Comment: did you try passing the data_m as a pointer? As suggested here in [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html).

Comment: @MarKS `float data_m[]` decays to a pointer when used in `cv::Mat(4,4,CV_64F, data_m)`. I doubt that this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `double` (64 bit, `CV_64F`) and `float` (32 bit, `CV_32F`).
When reading your float array as double your're going after the end of the vector, and you're reading uninitialized data.

Use either:

```
float data_m[] = ...
cv::Mat translation_m = cv::Mat(4,4,CV_32F, data_m);
```

or

```
double data_m[] = ...
cv::Mat translation_m = cv::Mat(4,4,CV_64F, data_m);
```

Comment: Opps sorry I overlooked that and thanks @Miki for your help I really appreciated it :)